# Drop specific data from a data array

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I am working on a data array with time, latitude and longitude dimensions.
The data array looks like the following:

```
print (data)
<xarray.DataArray (lon: 2, lat: 2, time: 48)>
 array([[[9.38898492, 6.65535271, 3.92192596, 1.83168364, 9.91812091,
     9.72198563, 0.23416978, ............],
  .......

    [0.38138545, 8.66420929, 4.62462928, 7.95165651, 2.06577888,
     6.0229346 , 8.26839182, .........]])

 Coordinates:
    * lon      (lon) float64 -99.83 -99.32
    * lat      (lat) float64 42.25 42.21
    * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-06-01 ... 2017-06-01T23:30:00
```

For each hour, there are two records at 00 min and 30 min. So the time dimension looks like :

```
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 48)>
 array(['2017-06-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T00:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T01:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T01:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T02:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T02:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T03:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T03:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T04:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T04:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T05:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T05:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T06:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T06:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T07:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T07:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T08:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T08:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T09:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T09:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T10:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T10:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T11:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T11:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T12:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T12:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T13:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T14:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T14:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T15:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T15:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T16:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T16:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T17:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T17:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T18:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T18:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T19:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T19:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T20:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T20:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T21:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T22:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T22:30:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T23:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T23:30:00.000000000'],
  dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

I want to keep only data recorded each hour at 00 min and drop the data recorded at 30 min. So the data will be like

```
print (data2)
<xarray.DataArray (lon: 2, lat: 2, time: 24)>
array([[[9.38898492, 6.65535271, 3.92192596, 1.83168364, 9.91812091,
    9.72198563, 0.23416978, ............],
     .......

    [0.38138545, 8.66420929, 4.62462928, 7.95165651, 2.06577888,
      6.0229346 , 8.26839182, .........]])

 Coordinates:
       * lon      (lon) float64 -99.83 -99.32
       * lat      (lat) float64 42.25 42.21
       * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-06-01 ... 2017-06-01T23:00:00
```

And so, the time dimension of the new dataarray (data2) will be like :

```
array(['2017-06-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T01:00:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T02:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T03:00:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T04:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T05:00:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T06:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T07:00:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T08:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T09:00:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T10:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T11:00:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T12:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T13:00:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T14:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T15:00:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T16:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T17:00:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T18:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T19:00:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T20:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T21:00:00.000000000',
   '2017-06-01T22:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T23:00:00.000000000'],
  dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Is there any method to do so ?

This is a code for reproducing the original data

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
import xarray as xr

precipitation = 10 * np.random.rand(2, 2, 24)
lon = [-99.83, -99.32]
lat = [42.25, 42.21]
time = np.arange('2017-06-01', '2017-06-02', 
                  timedelta(minutes=30),dtype='datetime64[ns]')

data =xr.DataArray(
    data=precipitation,
    dims=["lon","lat","time"],
    coords=[lon,lat,time]          
            )
```

Thank you!

Comment: provide your expected output in the question how you want to look at it. In the question you have initially asked to have the hourly data but what you are doing is to keep 24 hours or a day's data. Please rephrase the question as well with the expected output. Also provide the sample DataFrame in the question so that we can reproduce what you are doing

Comment: @think-maths : I rephrased the issue and provided a code for reproducing the data

Comment: Have a look at `regular expressions`, that should help you with your problem. Otherwise you could use some `split` functions which isn't the most convenient way to solve this but could work.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Your test data doesn't work. You need 48 `precipitation` values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this by using the [datetime components](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html#datetime-components) of your `time` values:

```py
data2 = data.sel(time=data.time.dt.minute==0)

print(data2.time)

#<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 24)>
#array(['2017-06-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T01:00:00.000000000',
#       '2017-06-01T02:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T03:00:00.000000000',
#       '2017-06-01T04:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T05:00:00.000000000',
#       '2017-06-01T06:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T07:00:00.000000000',
#       '2017-06-01T08:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T09:00:00.000000000',
#       '2017-06-01T10:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T11:00:00.000000000',
#       '2017-06-01T12:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T13:00:00.000000000',
#       '2017-06-01T14:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T15:00:00.000000000',
#       '2017-06-01T16:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T17:00:00.000000000',
#       '2017-06-01T18:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T19:00:00.000000000',
#       '2017-06-01T20:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T21:00:00.000000000',
#       '2017-06-01T22:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T23:00:00.000000000'],
#      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
#Coordinates:
#  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-06-01 ... 2017-06-01T23:00:00
#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resample`. resample returns `resample object` and then use the `pad` method

```
data.resample(time='1H').pad()

O/P
<xarray.DataArray (lon: 2, lat: 2, time: 24)>
array([[[0.93092321, 8.9256469 , 2.0902752 , 1.46022299, 9.63865453,
         3.06746535, 2.84095699, 9.4583144 , 4.81973945, 1.85398961,
         5.6259217 , 0.73004426, 8.48781372, 8.67918668, 7.19521316,
         6.67589949, 2.07546901, 1.4322415 , 2.13495418, 4.37055217,
         8.85306247, 4.43165936, 4.0294716 , 1.69092842],
        [0.52261575, 5.21821873, 1.32905263, 8.92984526, 1.81558321,
         3.89992125, 1.8788682 , 7.3124596 , 2.5068265 , 9.73076981,
         0.4511222 , 9.09497158, 0.89253979, 9.53972274, 7.15277816,
         0.08596348, 2.24376496, 2.06680292, 4.03876723, 5.55558076,
         8.26049985, 3.91292107, 8.43491467, 5.48503772]],

       [[8.34117163, 1.44051784, 2.78164548, 8.55049381, 9.43753831,
         7.35745785, 1.22652596, 9.55220335, 0.99754358, 9.3994966 ,
         7.92541645, 2.68894144, 9.61408994, 7.34960423, 2.74209431,
         4.19041801, 8.92849725, 9.98010787, 9.16994776, 4.75409515,
         3.10524118, 5.12308453, 8.61494954, 1.63399851],
        [1.02355383, 5.64350097, 5.76928407, 2.76870009, 6.86109118,
         9.1430836 , 1.81166855, 3.19906641, 2.28457262, 5.30030649,
         2.86022039, 5.46551606, 0.62270996, 7.86203301, 3.38400052,
         5.22623667, 5.49521413, 6.26552406, 0.93926924, 7.98750356,
         6.72156675, 9.5673477 , 3.03319399, 9.71812105]]])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-06-01 ... 2017-06-01T23:00:00
  * lon      (lon) float64 -99.83 -99.32
  * lat      (lat) float64 42.25 42.21
```